# Why this works (Templates, SFINAE). C++

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

referring to yesterday's post, 
this woke me up this morning. Why does this actually work? As long as the function `test` is concerned, this function has no body so how can it perform anything? I want to know why and how this works? I'm REALLY interested to see your answers.

```
template<typename T> 
class IsClassT { 
  private: 
    typedef char One; 
    typedef struct { char a[2]; } Two; 
    template<typename C> static One test(int C::*); //NO BODY HERE
    template<typename C> static Two test(…); //NOR HERE
  public: 
    enum { Yes = sizeof(IsClassT<T>::template test<T>(0)) == sizeof(One) }; 
    enum { No = !Yes }; 
};
```

Thanks in advance with help to understand this very interesting phenomenon.

Comment: For the Standardese, see `3.2/2` and `3.2/3` (both on definition of "use" and consequences of "using" something).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are refering to the Yes enum?  `IsClassT<T>::test<T>(0)`?  sizeof does not actually evaluate its arguments.  That's why code like the following is legal, even though you might expect it to bail out on you:

```
int* p = 0;
int sizeof_int = sizeof(*p); //oops, p is 0 :(
```

Comment: What I'm really interested in is why even though test has no body I get no error for this?

Comment: Because the return type is known at compile time without the body.  It's simply a `char` or `char[2]`.  That is all the compiler needs, and it's sanctioned by the standard.  To be clear, `sizeof` applies to the return value of the function (not, e.g., the code size of the function), and to compute that you only need to know the type, not have an actual object of that type.

Answer (score 8):

1. You can not get compiler error because `test`-function **declaration** exists.
2. You can not get linker error because you **do not call** `test`-function.

C++ Standart ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)

> **5.3.3 Sizeof**
>
> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the
>   object representation of its operand. 
>   The operand is either an expression,
>   which **is not evaluated**, or a
>   parenthesized type-id. The sizeof
>   operator shall not ...
>
> ...